# Logic free templates for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a technique for moving Ruby on Rails methods and logic (`<% if, link_to` etc.) away from templates. So far I have been looking at the [mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache) template language, but I am not entire sure if this is the way to go.

Any thoughts? Would you recommend mustache or is there a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache), there is [**Liquid**](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) (used by [Shopify](http://shopify.com)) and [**Radius**](https://github.com/jlong/radius) (used by [Radiant](http://radiantcms.org)). You may want to check them out.

Comment: have you used any of the languages?

Comment: I used Radius while developing a plugin for Radiant. I've only used liquid as an end user. Not as a developer. In my opinion Mustache looks like the simplest language among these for the end user, but I don't have an idea about how it fares for the developer.